# Xamarin.Forms version

Tags: xamarin.forms

When I create a new Xamarin.Forms project within Visual Studio it uses an old version of the Xamarin.Forms DLL (v2.0.0.6482). In nuget theres an update available to v2.3.0.107.

Why is an old version being used on project creation?

Im on the latest Visual Studio 2015 update and Xamarin version.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is expected since the Forms templates that ship with Xamarin for Visual Studio are not updated as frequently as the package itself. You can go ahead and update the packages to the latest version available on NuGet. Just make sure to update the Forms package in all the projects to the same version.

Note though, only update the Forms package inside the Android project and not the Android Support packages. Forms will also update those to the correct versions needed in order to avoid compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, sounds like it is an issue for a few people.

I have gotten it working with the help of a friend!

It's working fine for me now; I followed the steps below:

- Start a new Xamarin.Forms portable project
- Uninstall all Xamarin nugets, clear the packages folder (others will be downloaded)
- Close VS 2015
- Clear the `C:\Users_[Username]_\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips` folder, these will be downloaded automatically as needed.
- Open the project
- Update nugets then install Xamarin.Forms 2.0.0.6490, this should get the relevant version of dependencies for the android project (ie `Xamarin.Android.Support.x`). This will be v23.0.1.3, even though an update exists, as MatPag stated, it is not yet compatible.
- Build.

This will take a long, long time, as the `Xamarin\zips` folder will be re-populated so a quite hefty file will be downloaded.

Might complain again, clean, save then reopen.

This is will definitely work fine